# is_date() is malfunctioning

Tags: php, regex, date

i have a php methode that checks if a 
passed in parameter is a date. Here's it:

```php
public function is_Date($str){ 
        if (is_numeric($str) ||  preg_match('^[0-9]^', $str)){  
            $stamp = strtotime($str);
            $month = date( 'm', $stamp ); 
            $day   = date( 'd', $stamp ); 
            $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp ); 
            return checkdate($month, $day, $year); 
        } 
        return false; 
}
```

then, i test-drove it like this:

```php
$var = "100%";

if(is_Date($var)){
   echo $var.' '.'is a date'; 
} 

$var = "31/03/1970";

if(is_Date($var)){
   echo $var.' '.'is a date'; 
}

$var = "31/03/2005";

if(is_Date($var)){
   echo $var.' '.'is a date'; 
}

$var = "31/03/1985";

if(is_Date($var)){
   echo $var.' '.'is a date'; 
}
```

Note that each of the ifs also has an else statement as in :

```php
else{
   echo $var.' '.'is not a date' 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
100% is a Date
31/03/1970 is a Date
31/03/2005 is a Date
31/03/1985 is a Date
```

My problem is, why is 100% displaying as a date and why is `31/03/1985` not being read as a date ?

Any clue as to why will be highly appreciated as i am not too expertise in Regex

Comment: Why not simply check: `is_numeric( strtotime($str) )`?

Comment: what are you mean in `^[0-9]^`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd got it working now! the new output has stopped displaying 100% as a date, which was what I planned. Here's the final code snippet that does the job

```
public function is_Date($str){ 
    $str = str_replace('/', '-', $str);     
    $stamp = strtotime($str);
    if (is_numeric($stamp)){  
       $month = date( 'm', $stamp ); 
       $day   = date( 'd', $stamp ); 
       $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp ); 
       return checkdate($month, $day, $year); 
    }  
    return false; 
}
echo "A million thanks to you all ! you guys are the best !";
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using `^` at end of regex string, Meaning of `^` is to compare *beginning of string*.

Also, as [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92) suggested, you could simply use `is_numeric(strtotime($str))`

Your function should look like:

```
public function is_Date($str){ 
    $str=str_replace('/', '-', $str);  //see explanation below for this replacement
    return is_numeric(strtotime($str)));
}
```

[Documentation says:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Dates in the **m/d/y** or **d-m-y** formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American **m/d/y** is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European **d-m-y** format is assumed.

Comment: The `^` OP had were delimiters, which you've forgotten in your `preg` function.

Comment: i'd got it working now ! the new output has stoped displaying 100% as a date, which was what i planned.........